# Is it bad practice to produce and consume messages from the same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic, messaging, microservices, tibco-ems

Say you have a micro-service architecture where multiple services produce and consume *unit* statusses.

There are multiple ways to design this, which one would you recommend?

These are some options that come to mind:

1. Create a generic topic `unit-status` and make services consume and produce messages on this topic. This has the consequence that you consume your own messages and have to filter them. I would consider this a dirty solution, but easy for new new consumers to get all unit status events.
2. Create a specific topic for each status, for example `unit-status-created`, `unit-status-packaged`, `unit-status-loaded`, `unit-status-deleted`, etc. Each service produces only on it's own topic, but can consume from a list of topics, excluding it's own. For example the loading service would consume from list(`unit-status-created`, `unit-status-deleted`, `unit-status-packaged`). This allows services to show interest in only specific events, but it requires a code or config change in potentially all service when a new status topic is added.
3. Give each status it's own partition and consume from all partitions except the one you produce in. This design makes things more complicated (bookkeeping which partition contains a specific status), does not auto balance when partitions are added, adding partitions while live makes things a bit more risky, therefore does not have my preference.

Comment: Can you explain how you're using the unit statuses in the consumer services?

Comment: @WillC Consider two services unit-packing and unit-shipping. The unit-packing service emits a unit-packed status for a unit. The unit-shipping service consumes that status and allows shipping from that point forward. Once shipped, it also emits the status unit-shipped. Another (customer-service-service) wants to track the status of all units, and also consumes all statuses from the unit-status topic.

Comment: Why does the deletion service need to consume from other topics such as the unit-status-created and unit-status-packaged in your example for option 2?

Comment: @WillC That is indeed a bad example, i've updated the question and changed deletion-service to loading-service. It would want to know which units are packaged, because then it can start the loading process. It can clean-up it's state when units are deleted. It produces unit-loaded events once a unit is loaded

Comment: Curious what you ended-up going with here @Christophe - I am facing the same decision at the moment (but with SNS). Did option 1 work out?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding ,i will suggest point 1

**Addition of new Microservices**  it will be easier to add new microservices and that will still be able to work without much changes.

**Business Logic** should be part of microservice it self and not of messaging queue

Comment: Your statement about Addition of new topics is not in line with point 1, point 1 intents to have one generic topic all services use for a certain type of event. It does not add new topics. What do you mean there exactly?

I agree with the Business Logic statement.